# Want to create a form in flutter - fill with initial value -> edit by user -> save back

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and did not code for a long time.

I try to build a flutter app and in there build a list of item.
Now I want to edit one item of this list (swipeable list).

I open Editpage by:

```
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => EditPage(
                  Item: this.ListItem,
```

=> I give the selected ListItem over to the edit page.
There I can access it with "this.Item" for example in Text(this.Item.description)"

here is the "editpage" code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:models/list.dart';

class EditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ListItem Item;
  EditPage({this.Item});

  @override
  _EditPageState createState() => new _EditPageState(Item: this.Item);
}

class ListItem {
  int value;
  String name;

  ListItem(this.value, this.name);
}

class _EditPageState extends State<EditPage> {
  ListItem portfolioItem;
  _EditPageState({this.Item});

  void initState() {
    //final actValueController = TextEditingController(text: this.Item.value);

    super.initState();
  }

  //FormKey zuordnen
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final valueController = TextEditingController(text: Item.value);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    //valueController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Zurück'),
        //backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(this.portfolioItem.description,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Text(getCurrentDate()),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: valueController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'The Value?',
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter value!';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate will return true if the form is valid, or false if
                  // the form is invalid.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    // Process data.
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried several things and always get errors from this.

In the version above I get the error "Error: The instance member 'Item' can´t be accessed in an initializer.

When I move it to void initState() comes to the error "Undefined name 'valueController'.

Can you tell me or give me an example of how to do this right?

I want to edit my item on this page and then go back to the whole list, where I can see my changes.

Thx in advance
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a variable and pass it to other variable on class variables initialization phase. You should initialize you listener at `initState`, where `Item` is passed and when class instance created. Also, you can call a variable from a widget and a state by `widget.Item`, it also works for private variables.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:models/list.dart';

class EditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ListItem Item;
  EditPage({this.Item});

  @override
  _EditPageState createState() => _EditPageState();
}

class ListItem {
  int value;
  String name;

  ListItem(this.value, this.name);
}

class _EditPageState extends State<EditPage> {
  var valueController;

@override
void initState() {
    // final actValueController = TextEditingController(text: widget.Item.value);
    valueController = TextEditingController(text: widget.Item.value);
    super.initState();
  }

  //FormKey zuordnen
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    //valueController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Zurück'),
        //backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(widget.Item.description,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Text(getCurrentDate()),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: valueController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'The Value?',
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter value!';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate will return true if the form is valid, or false if
                  // the form is invalid.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    // Process data.
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```